# Open source c# XPath 2.0 filter

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, open-source

Can anyone recommend an open source, or at least freeware XPath 2.0 filter for c#?

I was looking at it for a while now, and I'm seeing only commercial implementations

Answer (score 3):

I guess by "filter" you mean an XPath processor.

[Saxon-HE .NET](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/#F9.4HE) is free, and open source. It includes XSLT 2.0, XQuery 1.0, and XPath 2.0.